# HDD Advanced Format help

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, mount

I am trying to install Ubuntu but I get no partitions showing up in the installer and running `sudo fdisk -lu /dev/sda` gives me:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x38a2f2da
Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048     206847     204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         93851793  204796619  110944827  52.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        204802048  757762047  552960000 263.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4           206849 1953521663 1953314815 931.4G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5           206912   93851729   93644818  44.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6        757764096 1310724095  552960000 263.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       1310726144 1953521663  642795520 306.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

I'm a total beginner with Unix and know this is because of WD's Advanced Formatting by Googling the issue but I have no idea how to fix it. I have a free partition that I want to install Ubuntu to but only `/sda` shows up as an whole block in the installer.

Comment: @RodSmith: I believe your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @Rodsmith I am not quite sure how I finally fixed the issue but in the end there was only an overlap problem that I fixed by changing the start position manually within gparted. I'm now comfortably within Ubuntu, thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

This problem has nothing to do with partition alignment (although there may be alignment problems, too). Basically, the problem is that two primary partitions (`/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3`) reside inside the extended partition (`/dev/sda4`). This is illegal. This problem can be fixed by my [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) program, which is part of the Ubuntu `gdisk` package; but proper identification of what each of those partitions does is necessary before proceeding. In particular, boot partitions should not become logical partitions.